# How to get the key from a calling preference

Tags: android, call, preferences, preferenceactivity

This is part of my preferences.xml. One of these preferences will call the same activity, *changePWEmail*, when the user click on either one of them.

```
   <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Security">
        <Preference
            android:title="Change email"
            android:summary="Option to change email"
            android:key="pref_security_email">
            <intent
                android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                android:targetPackage="com.test"
                android:targetClass="com.test.changePWEmail"/>
        </Preference>
        <Preference
            android:title="Change password"
            android:summary="Option to change password"
            android:key="pref_security_password">
            <intent
                android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                android:targetPackage="com.test"
                android:targetClass="com.test.changePWEmail"/>
        </Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

In the *changePWEmail* class, how do I get the key value (either "pref_security_email" or "pref_security_password") so that I can do appropriate action whether it is an email or a password change request? I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Security">
        <Preference
            android:title="Change email"
            android:summary="Option to change email"
            android:key="pref_security_email">
            <intent
                android:action="com.example.action.email"
                android:targetPackage="com.test"
                android:targetClass="com.test.ChangePWEmailActivity"/>
        </Preference>
        <Preference
            android:title="Change password"
            android:summary="Option to change password"
            android:key="pref_security_password">
            <intent
                android:action="com.example.action.password"
                android:targetPackage="com.test"
                android:targetClass="com.test.changePWEmailActivity"/>
        </Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

In your activity:

```
if (getIntent() != null)
  if ("com.test.action.email".equals(activtiy.getIntent().getAction())) {

  } else if ("com.test.action.password".equals(activtiy.getIntent().getAction())) {

  } else {

  }
```

In your Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.ChangePWEmailActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.test.action.email" />
            <action android:name="com.test.action.password" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.Launcher" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

google for Android intents and interactions.

Comment: Thank you momosxp. You made it clear enough. Use android:action instead of android:key. I'll give it a try shortly. Thanks again. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Android Studio latest beta version, and

```
activtiy.getIntent()
```

just raised up an error. Based on momosxp answer, so here is my version, which was tested and 100% working...
In the preferences.xml...

```
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Security">
        <Preference
            android:title="Change email"
            android:summary="Option to change email">
            <intent
                android:action="email"
                android:targetPackage="com.test"
                android:targetClass="com.test.ChangePWEmailActivity"/>
        </Preference>
        <Preference
            android:title="Change password"
            android:summary="Option to change password">
            <intent
                android:action="password"
                android:targetPackage="com.test"
                android:targetClass="com.test.changePWEmailActivity"/>
        </Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

In the activty...

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_pwemail_change);

        TextView txvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvChangeWhat);
        EditText txtOld = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtOldPWEmail);
        EditText txtNew = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNewPWEmail);
        EditText txtConfirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtConfirmPWEmail);
        Button btnCommit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCommitChanges);

        String ia = getIntent().getAction();
        if (ia != null) {
            if ("email".equals(ia)){
                ChangeWhat = CHANGE_EMAIL;
            } else if ("password".equals(ia)){
                ChangeWhat = CHANGE_PASSWORD;
            }
        }

        switch (ChangeWhat){
            case CHANGE_EMAIL:
```

... and you DON'T have to do anything to your manifest.